# How Can I Write A Statement To Print Out If The Number Is Odd Or Even in Java

Tags: java, bluej

I want to write A program To check and Print Out If The Number Is Odd Or Even.
This Is What I Have Programmed So Far:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Irs_Lab
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer :: ");
        int num = kb.nextInt();
    }
}
```

I Heard You can Use A % (mod) to get the remainder of division.
Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modular operator to see if a number is even or odd(as you said). When dividing a number by 2, if it is even it will have a remainder of 0, if it is odd it will have a remainder of 1. Using `if(a % 2 == 0){//even}else{//odd}` is your likely solution

Comment: Do I have to define the a variable?

Comment: You can use any variable.

Comment: Where should I put  if(a % 2 == 0)?

Comment: Put it where you want to print out if the number is even or odd, my best guess would be after you initialize the num variable. Its your own code after all!